# Как готового телеграм-бота задействовать без пк?

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot

Что нужно делать, когда телеграм-бот уже готов, но зависит от пк?
Не могу понять...
Принимаются все возможные ответы

Comment: Бот — это программа. Его нужно где-то запустить. Если у Вас нет возможности запустить его на своём ПК, то арендуйте чужой. Такие услуги предоставляют хостинг-провайдеры. Есть как платные, так и бесплатные хостинги.

Answer (score 3):

Если Вы про то как запустить бота вне своего компьютера, чтобы он работал, тогда:

- Heroku
- pythonanywhere
- AWS
- Azure
- Google cloud
- Яндекс.Облако