# Где разместить свой телеграмм бот?

Tags: python, telegram, telebot, бот

Я создал свой телеграмм бот и он работает когда я запущу программу (т.е свой бот) на локальном ПК.
И хочу сделать так что с ним можно было работать с другими устройствами везде и всегда.

Comment: Не выключайте свой ПК с ботом. Либо ищите хостинги на которых можно будет запускать бота, типа heroku

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1146497/234134 туда же можно добавить Oracle Free вечная бесплатная ВМ с Ubuntu Server (естественно ограничение по ресурсам, но для бота хватит). либо raspberry pi

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте Heroku. Можно залить на сервер <s>бесплатно.</s> Сам пользуюсь и вполне устраивает. [Вот](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9bJgcikmfHI) гайд по Heroku.

**UPD:** [Теперь хероку не будет предоставлять бесплатный хостинг ваших проектов, а так же удалит ваш проект, если он был не активен.](https://blog.heroku.com/next-chapter)

**Какие есть альтернативы?**

- [Railway App](https://railway.app/) - Вам выделеятся каждый месяц 5$ и 500 часов работы. Деплоить проекты можно с гитхаба.
- [Render](https://render.com/) - На месяц вам дается уже 750 часов бесплатной работы, деплой через Github
- [PythonAnywhere](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/) - Прост в использовании, но нельзя подключаться к сторонним сервисам

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй тут https://simplecloud.ru/start/34795
Сервер от 150 руб в месяц. Можно эксперементировать с ботами. Да и вообще для начала очень простой хостинг. Доступ к серверу будет по ssh.

Answer (score 0):

В данный момент стало трудно искать сервера, тк все заблокировано. Насчет Heroku - работает только с vpn и возможно во время оплаты, может быть неполадки. Но есть https://www.pythonanywhere.com/, если тг бот не имеет выхода в сеть, то бесплатная версия будет оптимальной, а так цены там небольшие